# Need Suggestion on the below implementation in SiebelOpenUI

Tags: siebel

In our implementation Siebel has been listening to the signalR hub and getting the values whenever it is posted in the server.

But now as the Dotnet SignalR Server is running on JSON supporting files, Siebel is also in need to refer the JSON files to receive the values from server.

Please suggest how we can refer a JSON file from Siebel.

Below are the js files Siebel is referring as of now.

> jquery.signalR-2.0.3.min.js
>
> jquery-1.6.4.min.js

we have the following Json files that SignalServer is referring to in dotnet:

> 1. Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core.dll
> 2. Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core.xml
> 3. Newtonsoft.Json.dll
> 4. Newtonsoft.Json.xml

My question is can we use the same Xml files mentioned above in Siebel to refer or is there any other approach to achieve the referring part.

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful edit @A.Hue

Answer (score 0):

I came to know from Siebel team here that it's not doable right now for some reason i don't know why. excuse me I'm not a Siebel resource.

And I called the send method in the SignalR server i created in c# Asp.net from my SignalR VB Client.

Siebel is listening to the Asp.net SignalR server and successfully receiving the input values now from the SignalR Client.